# Hotel Search API error when including children ages

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to retrieve Hotel Rooms by calling the following endpoint

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/shopping/hotel-offers/by-hotel?hotelId=YZDEN156&roomQuantity=1&adults=2&childAges=3&paymentPolicy=NONE&view=FULL_ALL_IMAGES

but it isn't working. I get this error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 400,
      "code": 4847,
      "title": "PASSENGER TYPE SELECTION NOT VALID"
    }
  ]
}
```

It works all right if I don't include the children ages (childAges parameter). Please could you let me know what I am doing wrong?

BTW, I am using developers.amadeus.com to hit the endpoint.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: childAges is a feature only available in Enterprise to access aggregators content.  We share the same API specification between Self-Service and Enterprise with minor changes. In this case, we wrongly published the API specification without removing the childAges parameter. The team will update it very soon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Are you planning to add childAges at some point? The API is quite lacking if we cannot book rooms with children...